# How to find files by content across lines with helm

Tags: helm

Within helm I'd like to find all of the files that have the content 'foo' and 'bar', even if 'foo' and 'bar' are on different lines.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a single grep command. I would do that with a command like `comm -12 <(grep -lr "foo" . ) <(grep -lr "bar" . )`, which you can enter in `M-x` `grep`, but the filenames wont be "click"-able.

Comment: That is a good point about grep. I've rephrased the question to better indicate what I really want.

Comment: Have you tried `helm-projectile-grep`? See the heading "Search in project" over here: http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html

Comment: `Grep v3.1` supports multi-line pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `helm-ff-do-grep` inside `helm-find-files` session.

- Inside `helm-find-files` session. You can invoke `helm-ff-run-grep` with C-s and C-u as prefix argument. Then choose where/what to search then it prompt you a pattern to search.

`helm-ff-do-grep` use ack or grep as backend. see https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#orgheadline11

Or You can use [helm-org-rifle](https://github.com/alphapapa/helm-org-rifle)

> In contrast with org-occur and similar commands, helm-org-rifle is entry-based (i.e. a heading and all of its contents, not including subheadings), while org-occur is line-based. So org-occur will show you entire lines that contain matching words, without any reference to the heading the line is under, while helm-org-rifle will show the heading of the entry that matches, followed by context around each matching word in the entry. In other words, helm-org-rifle is sort of like Google, while org-occur is sort of like grep.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to Helm, you can do this easily using [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

`C-x C-f` `C-M-j` **`foo`** `S-SPC` `C-M-j` **`bar`**

Translation:

- `C-x C-f` is the command for finding a file (`icicle-file`).  It uses [multi-completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) input (like the Helm command you are used to, I presume).  This means that you can match either file *name* or file *content*, or both.  In this case, you apparently do not care about the file names, so you match only the content (see next).
- `C-M-j` is (by default) the key that separates file-name pattern from file-content pattern.  You can use any key you like for this -- it's customizable (but there is a good reason for this odd-seeming default value). You use this key immediately, because there is no file-name pattern to match in your case. You use it to go on to specifying a file-content pattern.
- `foo` is the first pattern that you want the file content to match.
- `S-SPC` is the key to narrow to the current set of completion candidates, in this case, all files that contain a match for `foo` (which in this case is a literal pattern, so all files that contain `foo`). You can think of this key as "locking-in" a set of matches so that they become the new domain to match against. (Again, the key that does this is only `S-SPC` by default; you can customize it to be any other key.)
- `C-M-j` again, to skip a file-name pattern and provide another file-content pattern.
- `bar` is the second pattern that you want the file content to match.

What you see now is the set of files you are after. You can choose one to visit, or you can visit [all of them](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Choose_All_Candidates) at once (using `C-!`).

[Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#SecondExampleMultiCompletion) is another example you can follow, with explanations: